# Selenium python see in Google Devtools Console but Selenium returns error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get information from pianomarvel.com, the list of songs in the music library.

When I enter `$x("//div[@id='library-list']//div[@class='piece ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle']")` in the Devtools Console I get an array of 89 elements.

When I run `driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id=\"library-list\"]//div[@class=\"piece ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\"]"))`, I get an error TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

I saw that Puppeteer from Node.js will let you use $x.  Is there similar functionality for Selenium?

Thanks

Comment: I appreciate your response and the work you put in.  However, the library you listed has about 7,000 entries.  There is another music library that you access by getting a free account and logging in to pianomarvel.  This one has around 25,000 entries.  This is the library I am interested in and the one I am having trouble with.  I'm sorry I didn't mention it.  It was my mistake.  However, i was not aware that this smaller library even existed.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will retrieve the first page of the [music library](https://pianomarvel.com/music-library).
If you see Errors, then you may need to adjust the sleep time to a longer timeframe.

- The webpage is **maximised** to ensure we retrieve all of the columns
- The **table headers** are extracted with the following **XPATH**: `/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/table//th`
- The **table values** using this **XPATH**: `/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/table//tr`
- The headers and values are combined to create a dataframe containing the table's contents.

Here is the code:

##### Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://pianomarvel.com/music-library")

# Mazimize current window
driver.maximize_window()

sleep(5)

# Get Table headers
headers = [th.text for th in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/table//th") if th.text != '']

rows = []
for tr in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/table//tr"):
    columns = []
    for td in tr.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td'):
        try:
            columns.append(td.text)
        except:
            print("Error")
    if len(columns) > 0:
        rows.append(columns)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
print(df)
```

##### Output:

[image: DataFrame]